# Sed substitution with back reference not working

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I receive output from a program as tab separated values, of which I am trying to obtain the second only using sed. I am currently using this:

```
sed -r -e "s/(^[^\t]+\t)([^\t]+\t)(.*$)/\2/"
```

However it does not seem to find matches. I have tried it in [rubular](http://rubular.com/) were it does give me the match I want.

[image]

Comment: In Rubular, you are *matching*, not replacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a specialized tool for selecting columns from text files called cut:

```
cut -f2 file
```

Here we instruct it to select only the second column, see the manpage for more information. Tab is the default column separator.